# public_html/tmp permissions not right?

Tags: joomla, ftp, permissions

I have joomla 3.4.5 and I am trying to get an extension (csvi) to work. I seem to  have a problem with the puplic_html/tmp folder. Using filezilla I can see the permissions are 363.

The extensions says public_'html/tmp not writable', and there is a fix folder button which pops up with a helpful message telling me the same thing - ie folder not writable.

I have temporarliy set the permissions to 777 on the cPanel and the errors are still there.

When I try to do an import I get:

```
JFolder::create: Could not create folder.Path: /name/public_html/tmp/com_csvi/1446119320
```

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

You've probably used a wrong tmp path in your Joomla configuration.
Check if your hosting provider has already a tmp directory in place for you, something like `/name/tmp` and edit that in place of the `public $tmp_path = '/name/public_html/tmp';` line of your Joomla's `configuration.php` file.